# How to view executed redis commands in ServiceStack.Redis?

Tags: logging, redis, servicestack, servicestack.redis

I'd like to better understand what ServiceStack.Redis is doing under the hood. My hope was that I could hook up a debug/console logger and it would just output the executed commands to that logger, but I haven't been able to find the appropriate API. I did find several references to using `LogManager.LogFactory = new DebugLogFactory` but even after doing this nothing from ServiceStack appears in my debug output.

I also tried using the MONITOR command from the redis-cli but there seems to be some problem with it when using the windows port of redis as it gives me the following error: `(error) ERR unknown command 'monitor'`.

Comment: It turns out the MONITOR command didn't work because the redis server I'm using disabled it.

Answer (score 1):

What version of MSOpenTech Redis are you running?  I just grabbed [2.8.9](https://github.com/MSOpenTech/redis/tree/2.8/bin/release), and monitoring is working.

On a side note, if you're interested in how ServiceStack implements specific commands, it might be worthwhile to browse around the [source](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/tree/master/src/ServiceStack.Redis).  On low level, ServiceStack has a [byte client](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Redis/RedisNativeClient.cs) that implements Redis commands in a 1:1 fashion.  The various clients and typed clients are built on top of that.  [For reference](http://mono.servicestack.net/img/Redis-annotated.png)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get ServiceStack to output the redis commands it was executing by calling `LogManager.LogFactory = new DebugLogFactory(debugEnabled:true)` where `DebugLogFactory` was not the built in one provided by ServiceStack, but a copy of the factory and associated logger from [here](https://t.co/O6mOPcd9Rl). This step was necessary because the release builds of ServiceStack (i.e. what you can get on NuGet) will not emit the debug information.

Answer (score 0):

A few links that might be of help :

http://mono.servicestack.net/docs/logging/logging-overview

https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/7126317769bc634bb59459d9f1386079ef50d287/tests/ServiceStack.Logging.Tests/UnitTests/Log4NetFactoryTests.cs